# How to connect Genymotion and Appium? Need to open an android app through appium in Genymotion emulator instead of android avd

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

I've installed appium and when I check with

```
appium-doctor
```

it shows the below results:

```
Running Android Checks
✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to "/opt/android-sdk-linux"
✔ JAVA_HOME is set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64."
✔ ADB exists at /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
✔ Android exists at /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
✔ Emulator exists at /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
✔ Android Checks were successful.
✔ All Checks were successful
```

I use Eclipse IDE.

I've installed Genymotion and also Genymotion plugin in Eclipse.

I want to execute an appium code by connecting it to Genymotion. My code works with default android avd but not with Genymotion emulator.

My process:
Start eclipse
start genymotion emulator through eclipse
start appium in terminal

when I execute the code no error is shown in console, instead

below content is shown for a long time but no response:

```
[TestNG] Running:
/tmp/testng-eclipse--387326283/testng-customsuite.xml
```

my code is:

```
package appipract;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;


public class toolsqaappium2 {
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
//Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.1.0");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");


capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.appname");
// This package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.appname.SplashScreen");     // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
  //Create RemoteWebDriver instance and connect to the Appium server
 //It will launch the Calculator App in Android Device using the configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
 // driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.56.101:5555"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void testCal() throws Exception {
   //locate the Text on the calculator by using By.name()
 WebElement two=driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
two.click();
WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
plus.click();
WebElement four=driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
four.click();
WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.name("="));
equalTo.click();
//locate the edit box of the calculator by using By.tagName()
WebElement results=driver.findElement(By.tagName("EditText"));
 //Check the calculated value on the edit box
assert results.getText().equals("6"):"Actual value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 6";

}

@AfterClass
public void teardown(){
//close the app
driver.quit();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you starting genymotion by clicking the exe?. Have you created a Emulator device in genymotion?

Comment: No. I'm using Linux - Ubuntu 14.04. I'm opening the genymotion through eclipse plugin. Yes, I've created an emulator device in genymotion.